# Is the Jones matrix always $2 \times 2$?

Tags: optics, electric-fields, geometric-optics

I have only seen a $2\times2$ Jones matrix. It makes sense that it has such dimension but is there a Jones matrix different from this? perhaps a general form?

Comment: What's a Jones matrix?

Comment: @hft It's an operator(matrix) that is used to transform one polarization state to another.

Comment: @CosmasZachos perhaps I missed a point but I dont see how the question from the link relates to mine. Thank you!

Comment: Read about the stokes parameters which generalize the concept but also take into account partial polarization and intensity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the field is not paraxial, i.e. if the curvature of the wavefront cannot be neglected, then the field cannot be reduced to two components in the plane and a full 3D correlation matrix can be constructed.  In this case, the $3\times 3$ correlation matrix defines something equivalent to a 3D polarization, and the corresponding Jones matrices are $3\times 3$.

See

> de la Hoz, P., et al. "Classical polarization multipoles: paraxial versus nonparaxial." Physica Scripta 90.7 (2015): 074030.

Note that a similar formulation was used to describe long seismic waves in

> Samson, J. C. "Descriptions of the polarization states of vector processes: Applications to ULF magnetic fields." Geophysical Journal International 34.4 (1973): 403-419,

and available [here.](https://watermark.silverchair.com/34-4-403.pdf?token=AQECAHi208BE49Ooan9kkhW_Ercy7Dm3ZL_9Cf3qfKAc485ysgAAAswwggLIBgkqhkiG9w0BBwagggK5MIICtQIBADCCAq4GCSqGSIb3DQEHATAeBglghkgBZQMEAS4wEQQMdTMUJS-FQn76B7QIAgEQgIICf1-6kYcWfxaIfDTRBzhlgrNCBB-Jndm4g4ldf0Vxu-8T8GzgbA-EvfWPpwrUei27qwfJshuMs67vXOneoXpzf3Fk7qTE7sXpc2zP1rTsm0ddF3XOhWG5Nc6TRVVijLFYrvqosslXIU9ISQ_DtQZ4BBoltxMCuE7DKCtPTX6Iv84QSLRzsksti4cGwAiOKvhO_7GRvZqvIWbroVHDoQRXXYXgaL5rcA3B2llt6dMdLKp3Y29LQuSue-wI98i2vcjN1mHz8TqcqO4B4bEUJFrO_E3UX0pv97Hph9pXkxRuHCIy1ClWxNAq22ZZVhle4KcdmKnG2AWjJefTaxqZO52mgqJLrgVHNHBAQuDx723X1uXqiVjV608g3Xev7BrjQWwQ3u9o6O7FQGcDU27w_JcqHg0v6coOAnBumPd6RVZtdMXrOt0zNnroCcpHtYKYBONpfM67M--rncGxquIMaVx8-ogoH7Lue067_WUCln-Jsc-CxhSXj6GzbUVpsGjho7z9So6AgGvoz8cQSPoY8uJMde49pSYmHQESQdpLx8wfANsEzkuHW7GYud_vleilvPZWN4G_3duqxZSaI8yuT4qt6WWez9tNSseunZrw0pVmH-jtwuiRSDFaKEnQsQux0jICbZ6n4DQp8244uEVpvYbqMf5OONIT2k7-RY4UsLOejNJaxGBuUhS0yVdyVHprZO5EElowjednff06Y1N5-6eM9GdhnsltpuNknhBPR5OSYibnrFza0svJ2m6U9hkH7X_pFXP_2xLtApXW3m1xGo0ERD0-SGgPcQrRB9xrd6fuB_mFZULZN8tXdWpqc-2e-w7yhV6DYOgJNA-L6DGIhqgV_Q). One will recognize the Gell-Mann matrices in Eq.(16) of this paper.